# Django - Cannot assign "<Product: Test Product>": "Reply.comment" must be a "Comment" instance

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm getting a Cannot assign "<Product: Test Product>": "Reply.comment" must be a "Comment" instance. error at new_reply = Reply(content=content, author=self.request.user, comment=self.get_object()) and don't know what to do to fix it.

views.py:

```
class ProductFeedbackView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'store/product_feedback.html'

    def get_context_data(self , **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        connected_comments = Comment.objects.filter(product=self.get_object())
        number_of_comments = connected_comments.count()
        data['comments'] = connected_comments
        data['no_of_comments'] = number_of_comments
        data['comment_form'] = CommentForm()

        connected_replies = Reply.objects.filter(comment=self.get_object())
        number_of_replies = connected_replies.count()
        data['replies'] = connected_replies
        data['no_of_replies'] = number_of_replies
        data['reply_form'] = ReplyForm()

        return data

    def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            reply_form = ReplyForm(self.request.POST)
            if reply_form.is_valid():
                content = reply_form.cleaned_data['content']
            new_reply = Reply(content=content, author=self.request.user, comment=self.get_object())
            new_reply.save()
            return redirect(self.request.path_info)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = comment_form.cleaned_data['content']
            new_comment = Comment(content=content, author=self.request.user, product=self.get_object())
            new_comment.save()
            return redirect(self.request.path_info)
```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,)

    content = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)


class Reply(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,)

    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)
```

Comment: so i answered your previus post and still you have bug in code: connected_replies = Reply.objects.filter(comment=self.get_object()). self.get_object returns Product not Comment

Answer (score 0):

It's the same error as I pointed out in [the other question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292316/cannot-query-product-must-be-comment-instance). Here is the line of code that is not working:

```
new_reply = Reply(content=content, author=self.request.user, comment=self.get_object())
```

The cause of this is also the same as your other question:
`self.get_object()` returns a Product instance as you defined `model = Product` on your View.

To fix this, you'll need to get the comment in your post method before creating the reply.

One solution for this could be posting the comment id with the reply data, for example as a hidden field. This id can then be used to get the comment instance where this reply belongs to. If you choose this solution, also make sure the comment actually belongs to this product as you don't want someone to just change the value of the comment id and be able to reply to any other comments.

Some additional feedback:

- You don't need to check for the request method in the post method as it's already the post method.
- You're now trying to save both a comment and reply whenever a post is done. You should either create different views for each post or add an if statement to check which form is posted. For example also using a hidden field with a value for that.
- The comment model defines a product and an author relation. Both being null=True and blank=True. I think you always want a comment to belong to a product and an author. So you should remove those. Same for reply.
- After a successful post, use a HttpResponseRedirect where you reverse the url of the product.

Comment: How would I use hidden fields, I've never heard of it.

Comment: @static-man https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp

Comment: Having problems trying to do it, can you please do a minimal reproducible example?